# How can I define a TypeAlias for a nested Generic in Python?

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, typing, nested-generics

I currently have this code

```
T = TypeVar("T")
Grid = Sequence[Sequence[T]]

def columns(grid: Grid) -> Iterable[list[T]]:
    return ([row[i] for row in grid] for i in range(len(grid[0])))
```

But I think the `T` in the alias `Grid` is bound to a different `T` in the return type of the function.

How do I define `Grid` such that I can write

```
def columns(grid: Grid[T]) -> Iterable[list[T]]:
    ...
```

I've looked at `typing.GenericAlias`, but can't see how it helps me.

(I'm aware that Sequence[Sequence[T]] has no guarantee that the grid is actually rectangular, but that's not the problem I want to focus on here.)

Comment: It looks good now. `Sequence[Sequence[T]][R]` will get `Sequence[Sequence[R]]`.

Comment: @MechanicPig That's correct! Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using type variable as a generic parameter, it can be replaced by other type variables, which is mentioned in the [Generic Alias Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type) (but I only found this one):

> The [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method of generic containers will raise an exception to disallow mistakes like `dict[str][str]`:
>
> ```
> >>> dict[str][str]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: There are no type variables left in dict[str]
> ```
>
> However, such expressions are valid when [type variables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) are used. The index must have as many elements as there are type variable items in the `GenericAlias` object’s [`__args__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#genericalias.__args__).
>
> ```
> >>> from typing import TypeVar
> >>> Y = TypeVar('Y')
> >>> dict[str, Y][int]
> dict[str, int]
> ```

So there is no problem with your current implementation. In the interactive interpreter, you will see:

```
>>> from collections.abc import Sequence
>>> from typing import TypeVar
>>> T, R = TypeVar('T'), TypeVar('R')
>>> Grid = Sequence[Sequence[T]]
>>> Grid
collections.abc.Sequence[collections.abc.Sequence[~T]]
>>> Grid[R]
collections.abc.Sequence[collections.abc.Sequence[~R]]
```

Mypy will also correctly analyze them:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence, Iterable
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
Grid = Sequence[Sequence[T]]


def columns(grid: Grid[T]) -> Iterable[list[T]]:
    return ([row[i] for row in grid] for i in range(len(grid[0])))


c1: Iterable[list[int]] = columns([[1, 2, 3]])  # pass
c2: Iterable[list[int]] = columns([[4, 5, '6']])
# List item 2 has incompatible type "str"; expected "int" (13:42)
```